# Unable top load asset from Flutter plugin

Tags: flutter

I am developing a flutter plugin, and when using the plugin I get `Unable to load asset` error. Do I have to do something special when using a plugin?

I have no problem loading images in the main application.

From pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter:
  # To add assets to your plugin package, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
   - icons/
   - icons/myimage.png # << Just to show, that this also is not not working
  uses-material-design: true
  plugin:
  ...
```

Also tried:
 - moving back and forth with TABs etc.
 - renamed the folder to assets

Using the image folder asset:

```
Image.asset('icons/myimage.png', height: 12.0),
```

I get this error:

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
flutter: Unable to load asset: icons/myimage.png
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To load assets from a non-application package, you need to pass the `package` parameter to methods that load the asset like

```
Image.asset('icons/myimage.png', package: 'my_package', height: 12.0),
```

See also docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.asset.html

To be able to use assets from a dependency (plugin or plain Dart package) follow https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#bundling-of-package-assets

In a dependency all files need to be inside `lib/` because only these files are available for package users.

The asset path in `pubspec.yaml` needs to start with `packages/package_name/some_folder_inside_lib`

```
flutter
  assets:
    - packages/my_package/some_folder_inside_lib/my_image.png
```

Currently there is another limitation, that all asset files need to be listed individually in `pubspec.yaml` in contrary to assets from the application project where listing the folder is enough.
Upvote and subscribe to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22944 to get notified about updates.

Comment: Also if the asset is only used by a Widget within the plugin itself?

Comment: I see. I haven't tried that. You need at least to pass the `package: 'my_package`' parameter  https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.asset.html `Image.asset('icons/myimage.png', package: 'my_package', height: 12.0),`

Comment: Thanks, adding package name to Image.asset did the trick. To keep it clean, and if you like, you can copy paste the comment you made - then I can resolve it as a missing package name? Thanks again Günter

Comment: What is the point of creating separate package if we need to specify assets in app's yaml

Comment: @Bawantha when you want to distribute them as a package or as part of another package.